# Workflow Services not showing in Service Menu

Tags: automator, services

All of a sudden my Automator services are no longer showing in the Service menu in Mail.

None of them.

All I see is `No Service Apply` (grayed out).

[image: mail]

I know they still work, if I open them in Automator in they saved location (Services).

Comment: Are any of them selected in Services Preferences that are appropriate for the current context? How do you 'know they still work'?

Comment: They are selected in Service Preferences, they work if I open them in they saved location. (Services)

Comment: So it's just the Mail app? What do you currently have selected in the app? Does the list change if you try selecting some text in an email?

Comment: tried that did not work :(

Comment: Hi @Buscar웃 did you manage to work it out? I would suggest making sure you are logged in the same user, because the services are not stored in the generic "library" folder, but in the hidden one, relative to the user. I always get there clicking on the "Go" menu (Finder) and pressing option to show the user Library button.