# Service does not appear in application menu

Tags: pdf, preview, services

I created a simple service, that applies Quartz Black&Wite filter (the only block in the program) to a currently opened PDF and would like it appear in Services menu in Preview app. I have chosen PDF to get in Preview app, though it does not appear in apps menu (setting Files and Folders didn't work too).
The service in ~Library\Services, it shows up and is checked in Preferences.
Other services though appear correctly (i.e. Finder services).

I have created it this way: chosen to create a Service first, then set to get PDF in Preview.app, then added a Quartz-filter. Saved and opened to add to library.

I have looked through related questions and in general everyone has the same issue, but I haven't found a suitable solution, so maybe someone has an insight on requirements for a service to appear in context or app menu.
[Automator service not showing in services menu](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/233274/202631)
[Workflow Services not showing in Service Menu](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/132531/202631)

Comment: Can I suggest it may be worth you [editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/297270/edit) your question to clarify how you've created the service? Also, since you say that *in general everyone has the same issue*, it'd be good if you can link to one or two examples of these?

Comment: @Monomeeth These are the closest, though some other have services disappear or not showed, but have different causes.  My service is very simple.

Comment: @user3439894 then what kind of services that process PDFs are supposed to work in Preview?

Comment: Let me rephrase my now deleted previous comment... For a Automator Service to show in the Services menu in Preview you would need to set **Service receives no input**. For it to appear only in Preview you would need to set **Service receives no input in Preview** The problem though, because Preview's `has scripting terminology` is set to `false` it will be limited as to what would actually happen within Preview itself from how the _workflow_ is defined.

Comment: @user3439894 so I tried setting No input, but it still didn't appear in the menu. Well, if Preview has that menu, I guess there are services for it.

Comment: As you can see in [this linked image](https://i.imgur.com/8RjwwdS.png) it can appear on the Services menu in Preview. That said, even so, it's not going to process anything within Preview itself because the Apply Quartz Filter to PDF action applies a selected Quartz Filter to  PDF documents, the file itself. To do so, this action must be passed a PDF file as a filesystem object, not an opened document in Preview per se. Therefore, you'd have to ascertain the path filename of the opened PDF in Preview and pass it to the action. The change will not appear in Preview until the file is reopened.

Comment: I'm also not saying it can be done, I'm just trying to get you to understand how in this use case it works. It may be possible though, I haven't tried. As to it not appearing in the menu, I'd delete the service and recreate it using the aforementioned settings and save it for the first time anew. This hopefully will cause it to appear. However it's mute it you can't pass the path filename of the opened PDF document to the action.

Comment: @user3439894 processing a PDF as a file from Finder is a possible way, but that requires rewriting/duplicating file, when changes need to be viewed amid editing. Even if Preview can't do straightly what I wanted it to do, I would like to experiment with it, but the service still doesn't appear even after creating a new service file, relaunching Preview and sudo purging.

Comment: What version of OS X/macOS are you running?

Comment: @user3439894 10.12.5 Sierra. Does a particular MacOS version is known to have issues with services?

Comment: Under macOS 10.12.5, with **Preview** _closed_, in **Automator** I created a _service workflow_ setting **Service receives no input in Preview** and saved it as **Preview Test Service** without any _actions_ added. I opened **Preview** and it showed **Preview Test Service** on the **Services** menu in **Preview**. So, it does work to show an **Automator** _service workflow_ on the **Services** menu in **Preview**.

Comment: @user3439894 Hm, empty service workflow works for me too. Seems like it's sensible to content.